# iScroll: how to disable automatic initial bounce

Tags: javascript, iscroll

Is there a way to disable the automatic initial bounce every time you do a full refresh of the page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the bounce complete if you like to:

```
setTimeout(function() 
    {
        myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
            bounce: false //do not perform a bounce at all
        });

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

        },0);
```